# Interpretation of the word "as" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, american-english, speech

Consider the sentence "1/50 is 0.02 as a fraction."

Which interpretation is correct, whether it is factually correct or incorrect? (That is, consider there to be a clear distinction between fractions (p/q) and decimals (...dddddd.dddddd...).)

- 0.02 is the fraction
- 1/50 is the fraction

More generally, given a sentence "A is B as C", is A of type C, or is B of type C?

Comment: 0.02 is not a fraction. 0.02 as a fraction (in the form of a fraction) is 1/50.

Comment: @user66974

I understand that 0.02 is not a fraction; I want an interpretation that matches common English, whether it is factually correct or not. That is, would someone hearing this possibly interpret the statement to mean "0.02 is the fraction"? The example is silly, which is why I offered the general statement. Also, your sentence switches the order of the words to "A as B is C," but I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: _Fraction_ has a lot of meanings, and only some of them are taught in grammar school. Mathematicians call them "rational numbers", and don't care how they're represented. There are things called "continued fractions" and "continued decimal expansions" that are not the same, but they're both reachable.

Comment: Obviously the second meaning, "1/50 `|` is  `|` 0.02 as a fraction." So A is of type C.  The 1/50 is a fraction, and the 0.02 is a fractional value. But it would be clearer as "1/50 is 0.02 **expressed** as a fraction."

Comment: *0.02 as a fraction is 1/50*. So *1/50 is 0.02 as a fraction*. But it’s more understandable the first way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (i) it is based on an invalid example; (ii) appears in dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

The word "as" has to be reckoned with as a preposition in this context ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/as)).

- Hunting as entertainement is the main type of hunting today, although the ancestral and primitive aspects of hunting as a means of getting food is still part of it. (user LPH)

The principle of constructions of prepositional phrases modyfying a noun is that *the preposition must follow that noun*. It is also clear from simply reading the text of the above sentence that "as entertainment" is a prepositional phrase modifying "hunting". That is the only possibility.  To make that clear in the OP's sentence, (to show that the only possibility is that C modifies B), let's consider the following variant of the example sentence.

- Modern hunting is hunting as entertainment.

> "A is B as C", is A of type C, or is B of type C?

The idea of type is of no use in resolving the difficulty.

"fraction" (quotient) is a type and A *is* of type C, that is true; B is evidently not of type C, and that is so independently of all grammatical considerations (whether there is an "as" in your discussion or not).

The type of ".02" is certainly not that of a fraction (or quotient, more exact term), to put this more clearly; it is that of a decimal.  Nevertheless it is connected to C and not to A; however, the connection or relation (proper term) is *not type* but *equivalence*. ".2" is an equivalent of a fraction in virtu of a (mathematical) system of correspondence of notation, it is the *decimal equivalent* of the fraction "1/50". This equivalence is signified by "as".

- (Modern hunting) (A) is (hunting) (B) as (entertainment) (C).

The type of hunting of modern hunting is hunting as entertainement, that is, the type of A is "B as C"; you can also say that the type of A is C (modern hunting is entertainment at large); the type of thing which  hunting is, is not generally entertainement. Again B is not of type C. so it should become apparent that the idea of type is of no help, not relevant to the question.